# iPhone App on click of home button closing app instead suspending

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4

Hi in my iPhone app if use for sometime and click home button of iPhone and then again tries to reopen app app is launching from beginning its not suspending(its not pausing and playing),but sometimes it works fine, in all of iPads it works fine.
What may be the reason for this any help is thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have opted out of background execution by specyfing the key 'UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend' as YES in your applications plist file. See the attached image (iOS 5) and check your application's plist.[image]

And as you have specified that it happens only sometimes I assume that it may be an **application crash**.